# How to fix not working "android:background" in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml

When I use `android:background` with `Button` this appearance of the button does not change but when I use this with `TextView` or `ImageButton` it works correctly. The problem occurs in all layout files in project.

How to fix this ?

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    //Not working
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button"/>

    /Working
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"/>





</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".Activity.AddTaskActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity.AddActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TutorialActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PlanNextDayActivity" />

        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseMessages"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" /> 
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />

        <activity android:name=".BuyPremiumActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SelectColor"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.SelectIconActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.AddReminder"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party but I was having this issue as well. I could not set the font or background for a Button in XML. I have found that simply creating your own Button class that extends from Button works to fix this issue.

Not the most ideal solution but it works and is easy enough

Java:

```
public class MyButton extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton {

    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
      
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<com.example.yourpackage.MyButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/mybackground"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this is the code to use background in button and kindly the above provided is  manifest xml  provide your activity xml
<Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="testing"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
```

Comment: `android:background` not working with `Button` in my project. But work with `ImageButton` and `TextView`.

Comment: i had use this code and its working kindly check as if there is some other error